# How to disable SSL and switch to TLS for Openssl on fedora?

Tags: ssl, openssl, fedora

I am trying to block SSL as a measure against Poodle vulnerability.

Is it possible to alter the ciphers list rather than do something to disable the SSL compatibility and switch to TLS???

Answer (score 0):

Individual servers must be configured to disable SSL and use TLS exclusively - it is not a system-wide configuration.

I expect that most software in the official Fedora channels will have been updated to disable SSL where possible, but you will need to check that the server software you are using is configured appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
How about when we access through SSH and we would like to configure the Openssl to stick with TLS and disable SSL???

Comment: @pruthvivinayak SSH does not use SSL/TLS at all; it has its own protocol

Answer (score 0):

> How to disable SSL and switch to TLS for Openssl on fedora?

For OpenSSL, the answer is platform agnostic.

To disable SSL and only allow TLS, perform the following:

```
const SSL_METHOD* method = SSLv23_method();
if(NULL == method) handleFailure();

SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
if(NULL == ctx) handleFailure();

const long flags = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION;
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, flags);
/* No error code returned */
```

The `SSLv23_method` says "give me SSLv2 and above". You then remove the unwanted SSLv2 and SSLv3 protocols with `SSL_CTX_set_options`.

You should also call `SSL_set_cipher_list` to set your preferred cipher list. Something like:

```
const char* const PREFERRED_CIPHERS = "HIGH:!aNULL:!kRSA:!PSK:!SRP!MD5:!RC4";
res = SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, PREFERRED_CIPHERS);
if(1 != res) handleFailure();
```

***IF*** you control both the client and server, then only use TLS 1.2 and the AES/GCM and Camellia/GCM cipher suites. If you are interacting with compatible servers, then ChaCha20 is OK, too; but its not available everywhere (see, for example, [ChaCha20 and Poly1305 based Cipher Suites for TLS](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-agl-tls-chacha20poly1305)
).

The GCM cipher suites (and the ChaCha20 stream cipher) avoid some bugs built into the protocol at the architectural level. They are the cause of the padding attacks.

---

> Is it possible to alter the ciphers list rather than do something to disable the SSL compatibility and switch to TLS???

No. Protocols and cipher suites are two different things. You have to address them in turn.

Comment: jww and @frasertweedale thank you guys for the information. I did try the SSl_CTX commands and it worked just fine (@jww your code is simpler than what i tired). But that reset my entire SSH on the machine.  I am still trying to figure out a way that lets me just update the conf file. 
Thanks again guys !